# Visual studio 2019 - Publish to a folder does not publish all files

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.3.6

I have a simple ASP.Net core 3.0 website project (mostly empty at this point), but I did add a web root folder (www) and a static index.html file within that folder, as shown below:

```
website0
 > www
   - index.html
 > Program.cs
 > Startup.cs
```

When I try to publish to a folder locally (as a test), for example, I specify the destination as:

```
D:\ws0
```

All of the required files are copied, **EXCEPT for the "www" folder and any files within it**.

Hence, when I run the project, I get 404 errors because the static files were NOT copied during the publish operation.

WHY????

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around in the documentation at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.0#folder-publish-example

I found this little tidbit:

> When publishing ASP.NET Core web apps, the following assets are
> included:
>
> ```
> - Build artifacts
> - Folders and files matching the following globbing patterns:
>   **\*.config (for example, web.config)
>   **\*.json (for example, appsettings.json) 
>   wwwroot\**
> ```

Since I used "www" instead of "wwwroot", I suspect the "www" folder (and anything within) will NOT be copied.

**SOLUTION:**

1 - In Visual Studio, right-click on the project name, then click on "**Edit Project File**"

2 - Include the following entry in the {project-name}.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Include="www\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

3 - Save the file.

When you setup a Publish profile, the "www" folder and anything beneath will be included.

Comment: This solved it for me, but I didn't need to include the "CopyToPublishDirectory" attribute.