# How to define a static file as a start page in ASP.net app service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an old site (ASP.net) that I want to publish with azure app service. 
I created an app service with RuntimeStack=ASP.Net v3.5 and deployed successfuly.

**App Service** details:

> [image: App Service details]

But I have a problem with the start page:
I want the default page to be a static file (index.html). I tried to add the index.html in "Default documents":

> [image: Default Documents]

but without success. I get 403 error:

> [image: 403 error picture]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `index.html` was actually **published** to the App Service? If you open it with `(yoursite)/index.html` and it gives a 404 error, then it isn't there.

Comment: @PeterB You are right!   
'(mysite)/index.html' returns 404.
I published via the visual studio wizard, so why this file wan't published? And how can I publish this file now?

Comment: Try if this answer works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551338/1220550 (or else look for similar options, since you are not using .NET Core)

Comment: Can you provide code for web.config? The problem that index.html does not exist can be solved by modifying the .csproj file locally like this(then build and deploy):
  `<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="index.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>`
But I think your question is more than that. Can you provide the web.config file of your web app?